# "Error: Main method not found in class Grad, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)"

Tags: java

I get this message
by java compiler
"Error: Main method not found in class Grad, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)"

this is my (from the book) code:

```
class Grad {
      String naziv = "nepoznat";
      int brojStanovnika = 0;
}

class TestGrad {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            Grad g1 = new Grad();
            Grad g2 = new Grad();
            Grad g3 = new Grad();
            g1.naziv = "Belgrade";
            g1.brojStanovnika = 1600000;
            g2.naziv = "Njujork";
            g2.brojStanovnika = 20000000;
            g3.naziv = "Vankuver";
            System.out.println(g1.naziv);
            System.out.println(g1.brojStanovnika);
            System.out.println(g2.naziv);
            System.out.println(g2.brojStanovnika);
            System.out.println(g3.naziv);
            System.out.println(g3.brojStanovnika);

  }
```

}

very frustrating, please help :)

Answer (score 5):

make your `TestGrad` public and be sure that the file name is also `TestGrad.java`

```
class Grad {
      String naziv = "nepoznat";
      int brojStanovnika = 0;
}

public class TestGrad {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            Grad g1 = new Grad();
            Grad g2 = new Grad();
            Grad g3 = new Grad();
            g1.naziv = "Belgrade";
            g1.brojStanovnika = 1600000;
            g2.naziv = "Njujork";
            g2.brojStanovnika = 20000000;
            g3.naziv = "Vankuver";
            System.out.println(g1.naziv);
            System.out.println(g1.brojStanovnika);
            System.out.println(g2.naziv);
            System.out.println(g2.brojStanovnika);
            System.out.println(g3.naziv);
            System.out.println(g3.brojStanovnika);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main method is defined in the TestGrad class, so that's what you should try to run. Not the Grad class.